# Sliding in Android App

Tags: android

I have 5 photos, I want to put them in sequence. A person could be able to swipe (forward and backwards) through those photos with his fingers. Without using any animation which is the simplest wayof doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A viewpager could do it. Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewPager for that, go to following link ,

[Android ViewPager](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/)

[On Github find ViewPager](https://github.com/AndroidBegin/Android-ViewPager-Gallery-Images-and-Texts-Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example for swipe image viewer

https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer

check this out...